# TWA bases app sometime showing URL and sometime working, even Assetlink.json uploaded properly

Tags: progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, digital-assets-links

I have website (https://www.kriscent.com/product/kart-supermarket/). I created PWA of that after that I uploaded it on Play store by using TWA(Trusted Web Activities), App URL is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.kriscent.kartlite.
The URL of website always show in app, So I uploaded the assetlink.json (URL: https://www.kriscent.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json).
After uploading the assetlinks.json, When I run my app, the website URL disappeared but when I switched on other link in the app then the URL shows again.
I don,t know what is happening. Please help me if anybody has idea to resolve this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvUHL.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA7nr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, when navigating to a product detail page, you are using a different origin than the one used to open the Trusted Web Activity and that doesn't have Digital Asset Links setup:

- When the application is started, it opens https://www.kriscent.com/, which is correctly validated.
- When clicking on a product, the user is take to https://kriscent.com/ (without www), which is a different origin, and is not validated in the Android app.

It is possible to [get the Trusted Web Activity to work with multiple origins](https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity/multi-origin) but, in this case, I'd recommend using a single origin for the initial URL and the navigations, as you will be able to take advantage of using the same service worker, browser storage, etc.